# Как вызвать много раз tvStart?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{ 
    TextView tvStart; 
    int right = 21; 
    int left = -1; 
    int currentNum; 

    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){ 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
        tvStart = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvStart); 
        tvStart.setOnClickListener(this); 
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onClick(View v){ 
        String p = Integer.toString(currentNum); 
        switch(v.getId()){ 
            case R.id.tvStart: 
                AlertDialog.Builder aDb = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this); 
                View Builder = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main,null);    
                currentNum = (left + right) / 2;     
                aDb.setMessage("Ваше число " + currentNum); 
                aDb.setCancelable(false); 

                aDb.setPositiveButton("<", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){ 
                    @Override 
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){ 
                        right = currentNum;
                    } 
                }); 

                aDb.setNeutralButton("=", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){ 
                    @Override 
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){ 
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Угадали", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                        left = 0; 
                        right = 20; 
                    } 
                }); 

                aDb.setNegativeButton(">", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){ 
                    @Override 
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){ 
                        left = currentNum; 
                        if(currentNum>19){
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ошибочка", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                        }       
                    } 
                }); 
                AlertDialog aD = aDb.create(); aD.show(); 
                break; 
            }
```

Принцип работы: мы загадали число от 0 до 20 (в уме). Нажимаем на TextView, вызывается диалоговое окно с надписью: "ваше число N ?". Жмем кнопку "меньше", "больше", "равно", до тех пор пока не нажмем "=". Но проблема в том, что надо нажимать каждый раз на TextWiew.

Как сделать так, чтобы после нажатие кнопки диалоговое окно вызывалось само?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вызывайте `onClick(tvStart);` где надо, чтобы симулировать нажатие вместо пользователя.